# Finding the vertical asymptote of $f(x)=x^2e^{-1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, asymptotics, exponential-function

I'm having a problem finding a vertical asymptote for this function.
$$f(x)=x^2e^{-1/x}$$

I also looked for horizontal asymptotes, but there seems to be none of those.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-1}/x$ or $e^{-1/x}$? Please use MathJax in equations for better clarity.

Answer (score -2):

$$f(x)=x^2e^{-1/x}$$ is the same as $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}$$

Observe that $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}=+\infty$$ and so $x=0$ is a vertical asymptote (see [here](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-a-vertical-asymptote-in-calculus#:%7E:text=The%20vertical%20asymptote%20is%20a,the%20function%20does%20not%20exist.&text=On%20the%20graph%20of%20a,as%20x%E2%86%92x0%20.) for the precise definition).

There is no horizontal asymptote because if you consider rewriting as $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^0e^{1/x}}$$ then the leading exponent in the numerator $2$ is larger than the leading exponent in the denominator $0$.

Alternatively, you could determine if there is a horizontal asymptote by computing $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \mbox{-}\infty}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}$$

Comment: Foiledit24, if we take $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}=0$ but if $x=0$ is vertical asymptote must be infinity . right?

Comment: @00GB I will update my answer to include the calculus definition of a vertical asymptote, thanks

Comment: The first limit you have written, which is this: $$\color{red}{\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}=+\infty}$$ is incorrect. Perhaps you meant to write either $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}=+\infty$$ or $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{x^2}{e^{1/x}}}=0$$

Comment: My mistake, I forgot that the exponent was negative so I was looking at wrong graph